Android 11: USB debugging enabled in Developer Tools, but not actually running
my Pixel 2 has a hardware display issue, and I'm trying to access it from my Windows 11 machine by USB. The screen of the phone is barely working, but I can tell clearly that the "Enable USB debugging" switch is ON in Developer Options. However, when I plug the phone into the computer by USB, I'm pretty sure there's no "USB debugging is enabled" notification in the phone's notification tray, and adb devices comes up blank, even though I am able to browse the device's storage through the same connection via MTP.
The same exact setup works great with my other device, which is the same model on the same OS version.
What could possibly be going on here? Could it just be related to flakiness of the USB connection, even though MTP is working?

May be you have installed the wrong USB drivers for the affected device. Devices that have MTP and ADb activated should appear as three devices in Windows device manager (switch to view devices by connection): first the USB compound device and then the two child-devices, one MTP and one ADD device interface.

But as I mentioned, I have another basically identical Android device that works with the same Windows machine. Wouldn't that rule out having the wrong drivers installed?

I am not sure if Windows doesn't use serial numbers and other things to keep those two devices apart and allows to install different drivers. Just check the device manager and you will see.

I ended up concluding that it was most likely a hardware issue with the phone's USB port, since I've had other issues with that port working for some kinds of things and not for others.
